# How to get DataContext for UIElement?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, uielement

As `UIElement` has no property `DataContext`, how can I get the `DataContext` for `UIElement`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DataContext` property is introduced to the inheritance hierarchy in the `FrameworkElement`.

Because `FrameworkElement` inherits from `UIElement` you have to make sure the `UIElement` actually is a `FrameworkElement`:

```
if(uiElement is FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
{
    var dc = frameworkElement.DataContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast the `UIElement` to a `FrameworkElement` and then access the `DataContext` property.

Comment: With all due respect, this is not good advice. It is perfectly legal to create custom UI elements by deriving directly from `UIElement`, and this is perhaps even preferred if you want a lighter-duty control and/or don't need or want the additional layout and data-handling capabilities of `FrameworkElement`. Since the existence of non-FE controls can't be ruled out, "casting the `UIElement` to `FrameworkElement`" seems like shaky advice considering how little information was given by the OP.